# Geoserver WFS Authentication

Tags: authentication, geoserver, osgeo

I have been hitting my head in a wall trying to figure out how I can create a web framework for Geoserver WFS Authentication  as showed in attached.

I tried to configure the Credentials From Request Headers Filters, but still no achieving my goal.

So, I want to set up an **user** and **password** and only who has them can download raster (Geotiff) and vector data.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @IanTurton, first I created o role <wfs.* = ROLE_WFS>; second, I created an user <julierme> and I set ROLE_WFS to julierme; third, I configured the credentials as in [here](https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/suite/enterprise/latest/geoserver/security/tutorials/credentialsfromheaders/index.html). Now, I want to configure an authentication framework as the box in the previous message to anonymous users and julierme  to enter their credentials in order to download data (via WFS  and WMS (GeoTiff) request). I am not sure how to associate apachesession, ROLE_WFS and julierme/anonymous users.

Comment: That "GeoServer Realm" sounds to me like an authentication on Tomcat's side, not on GeoServer.

Comment: If you want to connect apache session with the user authenticated, maybe this? https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/security/tutorials/credentialsfromheaders/index.html